# How to add partitioned cookie attribute for session cookie set by weblogic server?

Tags: java, cookies, weblogic, session-cookies

Need to add partitioned cookie attribute for session cookie set by weblogic server.

I tried adding in partitioned attribute weblogic.xml but every time server is generating another session cookie while loading the webpage inside iframe [Third party cookies blocked in browser]. Is there any way to overcome this issue ?

I need the weblogic server to generate one cookie and reuse the same until the session is killed.

Comment: WebLogic may not directly support the Partitioned attribute in its configuration. The session cookie settings in WebLogic are usually limited to basic properties like name, domain, path, secure flag, and HTTPOnly flag. You might need to check Oracle's latest documentation or support for any new features or workarounds that specifically address the Partitioned attribute.